# Renaming in command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line

I have images with filenames like `0034343.jpg` and I want to remove the leading zeros, leaving `34343.jpg` as the new filename.

How can I do this in the command prompt? I tried `REN 00*.jpg *.jpg`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Do you want ALL leading 0's removed or just 2?  What if there are only 1 or no 0's?

Comment: just the 00 on the start if no zero remain its original filename

Comment: My usual method is to create a batch file using dir /b and excel formulae. There are probably better ways but I like my way since I understand it unlike batch programming. :)

Answer (score 5):

You should be able to start with:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
for /f "delims=*" %%a IN ('dir /b 00*.jpg') do (
    set file=%%a
    set newfile=!file:~2!
    echo move !file! !newfile!
)
endlocal
```

This will, as it stands, simply echo the `move` command. Remove the `echo` once you've finished testing. And keep in mind this may not work as expected if your file names have spaces in them.

Stepping through it bit by bit:

- The `setlocal` enables certain `cmd.exe` extensions, chief here being the ability to do delayed expansion of environment variables inside `for` loops.
- The `for` loop runs the cmd `dir /b 00*.jpg`, doing one iteration per file (setting `%%a` to the file name).
- The first `set` simply saves the filename into a variable. The second is a substring operation starting at the third character.
- The `move` will rename the file.

You can examine the various commands by entering `help` commands at the command line:

```
setlocal /?
set /?
for /?
set /?
```

Comment: I can't say I understand batch scripting that much but I tested and this seems to do the job. :) You might want to mention the removal of "echo" to get it to actually move rather than just display and to put it in a .cmd or .bat file in order to run it for people who have never really done this kind of thing. I'm sure there are plenty of people like that out there... :)

Comment: No probs, @Chris, I'm always up for some constructive criticism. Updated to (hopefully) make more useful.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
for %i in (*.jpg) do (
    set filename=%~nxi
    set newname=%filename:~2%
    ren !filename! !newname!
)
```

This will just strip two characters off the beginning of every file name.  Delayed expansion must be enabled.  Might need to do `cmd.exe /v:on` first on XP.