# Renaming a part of the title for multiple folders

Tags: command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Renaming in command prompt](https://superuser.com/questions/191019/renaming-in-command-prompt)

I was wondering if there is a command in Command prompt or Power-shell that can delete the same part of the folders name for all the folders in one go.

Example: For books from the same author but having different titles, I want to keep the books' title but remove author's name.

```
                   Authors Name The Title                             The Title
              Same Authors Name Different title 1                    Different Title 1
FROM THIS >>> Same Authors Name Different title 2   TO THIS >>>>     Different Title 2
              Same Authors Name Different title 3                    Different Title 3
```

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Renaming in command prompt](http://superuser.com/questions/191019/renaming-in-command-prompt) also see [How can I mass rename files from the command line or using a 3rd party tool?](http://superuser.com/questions/16007/how-can-i-mass-rename-files-from-the-command-line-or-using-a-3rd-party-tool)

Comment: YEAH!!! "How can I mass rename files from the command line or using a 3rd party tool?"   that threat had the solution for me there thanks alot =)